# Angular.js $scope not binding after $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

The UI binds but with {{total}} showing as -1
I do see the console log 'data came back'. Why dont I see 99 ?

```
myModule.controller('dashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$http'
    , function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.total=-1;
        $http.get('api/controlPanel/dashboard').success(function (data) {
            $scope = data.stats;
            $scope.total=99; // just to make sure the value changes
            console.log('data came back');
        });
    }
]);
```

I read a lot of blogs talking about $scope.$apply yet it is undefined. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what does it read if you comment out '$scope = data.stats;'?

Comment: Please don't assign data.stats to your $scope..

Comment: It is because of the asynchronous operation of the javascript. It executes your $scope.total and send a request to the server. Your html binds the -1 value. You need to delete the $scope.total = -1 and best practise is to use resolve method before you load the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first inclination is that you are redefining the $scope object and so the bindings are not taking effect. I would try `$scope.stats = data.stats` instead to avoid this problem.

This might be good to read: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Hope this helps!

Comment: 100% right. $scope carries a lot more than just data. By overriding it with my object I pretty much killed it.